# What does is_constructible_v<std::string&&, std::string&&> mean by?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, type-traits, rvalue

I can understand what is `is_constructible_v<std::string, std::string&&>`.
But what does `is_constructible_v<std::string&&, std::string&&>` mean by?

What is difference between `is_constructible_v<std::string, std::string&&>` and `is_constructible_v<std::string&&, std::string&&>`?

I think that `is_constructible_v<std::string&&, std::string&&>` means that construct rvalue from rvalue. But I'm not clear what does `constructing rvalue` mean. If T is just constructible, it's constructor always could be used as rvalue. Is this the meaning of constructing rvalue?

Comment: What does is\_constructible\_v<std::string&&, std::string&&> mean by what?

Answer (score 5):

`std::is_constructible_v<std::string&&, std::string&&>` tests if

```cpp
std::string&& obj(std::declval<std::string&&>());
```

is well-formed (see [[meta.unary.prop] p9](https://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.prop#9)), which it is. You are allowed to create an rvalue reference like so:

```cpp
std::string&& obj(std::string{}); // string&& from string&&
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the two statements do different things; the first one is binding a reference to an xvalue, and the second one performs temporary materialization. Currently, I think the only difference is that one works with private destructors/constructors, and the other doesn't.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I just tried to answer what it does (and hoped it would be worth _something_). The test could of course return `false` for `<foo, foo&&>` but `true` for `<foo&&, foo&&>`  which at least in C++14 would mean something :-) ... and thanks for the edit! Cheers!

Comment: I mean that `std::declval<T>` and `std::declval<T&&>` produce an xvalue (the `&&` is redundant, actually). The second code example you're showing is an example of temporary materialization because you're trying to bind an rvalue reference to a prvalue. It works too, but it only indirectly shows `string&& from string&&`. A more obvious way would be to bind to `std::move(a_string)`.

Comment: @JanSchultke Aha, the parameters part. Yes, I don't see a difference in that part either. It seems to me like OP is mostly concerned about the first parameter to `is_constructible`. I used the same form as is described in the type trait to make it easy to see how the trait could look in code that's evaluated. It was meant to show that what's being tested also works (in this case).

Comment: What is the usage of std::string&& obj(std::string{})? If obj is rvalue, it couldn't be referred after that line. And if std::string obj(std::string{}) is well formed, std::string&& obj(std::string{}) is also well formed I think. I am still confused what is the meaning and usage of is_constructible<std::string&&, std::string&&>. Is there any case that can disprove my sentence?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa The usage may be limited, but it was meant to show what the type trait tests. _"it couldn't be referred after that line"_ - Yes, `obj` is an rvalue reference. _"if `std::string obj(std::string{})` is well formed, `std::string&& obj(std::string{})` is also well formed I think"_ - Yes, but the opposite may not be true. The usefulness of testing if you can bind an rvalue reference to any `T` is questionable though since you can always do that.

Comment: ... it would be something different if the test was not `is_constructible_v<T&&, T>` but `is_constructible_v<T&&, U>`

Comment: _"The usefulness of testing if you can bind an rvalue reference to any T is questionable though since you can always do that."_ ... according to `is_constructible`. It may not hold true in reality though.

Answer (score 1):

`&`/`&&` in the first and the remaining parameters of `is_constructible` have different meanings.

In the second (and any following) parameters, they specify the value category: `&` for lvalue and  /`&&` for rvalue.

In the first parameter, `&`/`&&` are a part of the type of the variable we're constructing, not a value category.

So, in `is_constructible_v<std::string, std::string&&>` we're constructing a `std::string` from an rvalue of type `std::string`.

And in `is_constructible_v<std::string&&, std::string&&>`, we're constructing a `std::string&&` (a reference, not a string) from an rvalue of type `std::string`.

---

Here's an example how it could happen:

```
std::string a;
std::string &&b = std::move(a); // `move` here returns an rvalue of type `std::string &&`
```

Confusingly, `&&` near `b` and `&&` in the return type of `move` also mean subtly different things. The former makes `b` a reference. While the latter makes `move` return an xvalue, as opposed to prvalue (when returning by value) or lvalue (when returning a `&` reference). The latter doesn't produce any references, strictly speaking.

Comment: But in your example constructing of rvalue doesn't occur becuase std::move is just a type cast "a" to rvalue. How can your example explain my question?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa A reference `b` is being constructed. (Or rather "created", since only class instances can be "constructed".) Yes, no new `std::string` is created, but a new reference to one is created.

Comment: To be pedantic, saying *"constructing of rvalue"* doesn't make much sense. Rather it's "constructing (or creating) rvalue reference". Rvalue references and rvalues are different things, despite the name, which is the point I'm trying to make here.

Comment: So, when constructing rvalue reference with your example, is the constructor called?  From my understanding, ```is_constructible``` is for checking that corresponding constructor can be called without problem. But in your example, constructor may not be called. Am I correct?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa *"for checking that corresponding constructor can be called"* It's only true if the first argument is a class type, other types (such as references) don't have constructors. Generally, it checks whether a variable of the specified type can be initialized with the specified arguments. *"when constructing rvalue reference with your example, is the constructor called"* No, but that's not what we're checking. We're checking if we can initialize a reference `std::string&&` with an rvalue of type `std::string`.